# Silent push notification doesn't work on iOS7 in background mode

Tags: ios, ios7, notifications, push-notification

I have this weird situation, my app support iOS7 and above. what it does, it's enabled `Remote notifications` by using silent notifications.

I know that iOS7 and iOS8 above has different logic to handle notification. I did this :

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        }
        else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
             (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
        }
```

here's notification receives

```
    {
        aps =     {
            "content-available" = 1;
        };

    }
```

So what it does is, app receive silent notification, and then set localNotification, see below :

```
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    notification.alertBody = @"testing";
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]  scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

All it works in iOS8 and iOS9 in background mode and foreground mode. When app is in foreground, it will trigger `didReceiveLocalNotification`.

But when I was testing in iOS7, it doesn't work if the app is in background mode. I'm trying to figure out how this happen, while other OS working fine. I did test while app is open, it did receive push notification, and `didReceiveLocalNotification` get triggered. but when goes to background, nothing happen (no local push notification).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Silent Push Notification in iOS 7 does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239737/silent-push-notification-in-ios-7-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in this tread, aps need to include `priority` in order to work in iOS7.

```
 aps =     {
        badge = 7;
        "content-available" = 1;
        priority = 5;
    };
```

check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23917593/554740

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention about enabling Background Fetch. Have you enabled it in your App Capabilities?

and set this in your AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];

    return YES;
}
```

and this as your delegate method

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
    // do your thing here. maybe calling a view controller class or stuff
}
```

But if you're not into background fetch, try this instead:

```
{
    aps = {
        "content-available" : 1,
        "sound" : ""
    };
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I don't enable it, since I don't use `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:`. Btw, I reiterate iOS8 & iOS9 works. :(

Comment: any official statement to add sound key ? In the meantime, i will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly sure about the issue, but maybe you can try to change respondsToSelector.  Refer to the following:

```
if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
```