# IOS Newsstand background troubleshouting

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, background-process, newsstand-kit

I'm starting a newsstand application and first I'm testing all the framework to see who everything works. I already downloaded an issue triggered by a notification when in foreground. but I don't know how to download in background, or at least I'm missing something... Here is the stuff I added to plist:
[image: plist]

The app is targeted for IOS 5... here is my code... of course I also implemented the three URLConection methods of `NKAssetDownload`

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsNewsstandDownloadsKey] || [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {
        NKLibrary *nkLib = [NKLibrary sharedLibrary];
        for(NKAssetDownload *asset in [nkLib downloadingAssets]) {
            [asset downloadWithDelegate:self];
        }
    }else{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                                               UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                                                               UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                                               UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability
                                                                               )];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool: YES forKey:@"NKDontThrottleNewsstandContentNotifications"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    return YES;
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification");
if (userInfo) {
    NKIssue *issue4 = [[NKLibrary sharedLibrary] issueWithName:@"01_Primera"];
    if (!issue4) {
        issue4= [[NKLibrary sharedLibrary] addIssueWithName:@"01_Primera" date:[NSDate date]];
    }
    if([issue4 status]==NKIssueContentStatusNone) {
        NSURL *downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.viggiosoft.com/media/data/blog/newsstand/magazine-4.pdf"];
        NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:downloadURL];
        NKAssetDownload *assetDownload = [issue4 addAssetWithRequest:req];
        [assetDownload downloadWithDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

}

What am I missing, and also do I have extra unnecessary code? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are testing waking up the app (after swiping it away) with a notification with content-available:1 on iOS7, it has a bug: [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239737/silent-push-notification-in-ios-7-does-not-work) [and here (log in with your dev account)](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/209664?tstart=0).
  It should work on iOS 5-6, if you have a device to test that hasn't been updated.
- You also need a key in the Info.plist: [Required background modes - newsstand-content](http://www.viggiosoft.com/media/images/blog/newsstand/newsstand_info_plist.png)
- Finally in your code I think you should change a bit in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

  ```
  if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsNewsstandDownloadsKey] || [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {        
       [self handleNotification:launchOptions];        
  }

  //...other code...

  //This code can be the same as with didReceiveRemoveNotification

  -(void) handleNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo{

      //check userInfo for "content-available" key
      //if there is content-available:1 check for an issue_id/content_id in the rest of the notification payload (userInfo), and download the issue

  }
  ```

Comment: I already had the Required background modes - newsstand-content and my code is already like that. I tried opening the app then clicking the home button then sending the alert. I receive the alert but the download doesn't start. I tried with ios7.0.4 and with 5.1.1 and still same results. It works in foreground and also when I swipe the notification HUD in the lock screen to open the app. What else could it be, please help.

Comment: I FINALLY FIGURED IT OUT! I ALSO NEEDED Required background modes - App downloads content in response to push notifications