# iOS Remote Notifications not working when "content-available": 1

Tags: ios, push-notification

I can receive Push Notifications in my iOS app without problems, but if I try to send a Silent Notification adding "content-available": 1, I will not receive any notifications no matter the state of my app (even if it is running in the foreground)

I have checked the Remote Notifications checkbox. (or added remote-notification in .plist) and I have implemented application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler but didReceiveRemoteNotification only is called if I send a normal push notification and the app is running in the foregound

Any idea??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this answer on SO: [Silent Push Notification in iOS 7 does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239737/silent-push-notification-in-ios-7-does-not-work)

Seems like there is a bug that requires another field to be present for the remote notification to be valid.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested on iOS 7.0.6 to send a slient push with the payload:

```
{"aps":{"content-available":1}}
```

and worked fine, here is my userInfo object on Xcode:

```
2014-05-09 11:04:23.737 SilentPushTest[316:60b] PAyload {
    aps =     {
        "content-available" = 1;
    };
}
```

You can test sending push easily with this app:

https://bitbucket.org/jesuslg123/pushmebaby

Just need to add your app certificate with the name apns.cert and compile it.

Comment: Can you please post your didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler in the app delegate ?

Comment: Don't forget to enable on "Capabilities" the "Background Modes" and active the "Remote notifications" inside.  

`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler  
    {
         [logHelper addLogWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PAyload %@", userInfo.description]];
    
}`

I'm not sure how to properly format the code on the comment... @S_O