# iOS 8: App processing silent notification upon launch

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I've [read about the woes of silent push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239737/silent-push-notification-in-ios-7-does-not-work?lq=1) in iOS, so this will likely be fruitless ... but I figure I'll ask if only to ***just maybe*** have an Apple rep see it.

I'm sending a simple APNS message to an iOS 8.1 app:

```
    aps: {
        content-available: 1,
        priority: 5
    }
```

The app is in the background (read: I have **not** force-closed it).

Sometimes my app delegate's `didReceiveRemoteNotification` with `fetchCompletionHandler` fires, sometimes it doesn't.  I can tell because I am monitoring my server and can see if/when a GET request arrives.

I'm currently exploring if there's a correlation with passing weather systems and/or bird migration patterns.

But what's really frustrating is that when I build/launch my app via xCode, here's the console output:

```
- appDelegate: received notification
- appDelegate: fetching stories
- appDelegate: application launched
- appDelegate: remote notifications approved
 **** modal view controller: viewDidLoad
```

Notice the notification is "received" just as xCode is firing up the app, but ***before*** the application launches (?).

It's as though the device *is* receiving silent notifications but is sitting on them until xCode starts the app.  Additionally, I've noticed that when the device is running the app & connected to xCode, silent push notifications arrive very reliably ... which would also suggest some sort of irregularity involving xCode.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is anyone else seeing this phenomenon?  Or is this just a bug with iOS / APNS?

I'm happy to try out any code snippets or suggestions anyone has! Thank you.

Comment: @user3703910 Could you clarify which part of that thread you're referencing?  I read that before writing my question, but perhaps there's a part that I missed?  I am *not* force-closing my app (it's running in the background).

Comment: I also noticed that when I have my app running via Xcode to my device -- that it always receives the silent notifications. However, when I test it just via my device (without xcode) -- sometimes i get different results -- where the notification doesn't show up (even though I did not force-close my app).