# CloudKit Push Notifications didReceiveRemoteNotification never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, apple-push-notifications, cloudkit

I am using CloudKit to store user data and want to get push notifications when the records are changed or new records are created. But it does not work...

I **register for the subscriptions** like this:

```
- (void) updateCloudSubscriptions {

    NSPredicate *allPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"];
    CKSubscription *newOrUpdateSubscription = [[CKSubscription alloc]
        initWithRecordType:kMyRecordType predicate:allPredicate options:
        (CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordCreation | CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordUpdate)];
    CKNotificationInfo *newOrUpdateNotificationInfo = [CKNotificationInfo new];
    newOrUpdateNotificationInfo.shouldBadge = NO;
    newOrUpdateNotificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = YES;
    newOrUpdateSubscription.notificationInfo = newOrUpdateNotificationInfo;

    CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [[CKContainer containerWithIdentifier:kMyContainerID] 
        publicCloudDatabase];
    [publicDatabase saveSubscription:newOrUpdateSubscription 
         completionHandler:^(CKSubscription *theSubscription, NSError *saveError) {
        if (saveError){
            //error handling
        }
        NSLog(@"Subscription created");
    }];
}
```

This succeeds. On the CloudKit Dashboard the **subscription is created correctly**.

In my **AppDelegate** I now have the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
        (UIUserNotificationTypeNone | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
        UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

and these delegate methods implemented:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"%@ with token = %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), deviceToken);
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@ with error = %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error);
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}
```

**`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`is called successfully with a token. But `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is never called.**

I tested this by changing values on the Mac version of my App and on the iPhone version. Both upload the changes but neither triggers a notification. I also tried changing the values directly on the dashboard but that did not cause notifications either.

What am I missing here?

If relevant: I am on OS X 10.10 with XCode 6.4

I activated `apsd` logging but only get messages like this:

```
Jul 12 18:25:29 Mac.local apsd[44748]: APSMessageStore - Saving database.
Jul 12 18:25:29 Mac.local apsd[44748]: APSMessageStore - Destroying database.
Jul 12 18:25:29 Mac.local apsd[44748]: APSMessageStore - Closed database.
Jul 12 18:25:29 Mac.local apsd[44748]: APSMessageStore - Reopening database
Jul 12 18:25:29 Mac.local apsd[44748]: APSMessageStore - Initializing database on thread: <NSThread: 0x7f8f1bf80dd0>{number = 55, name = (null)}
Jul 12 18:25:29 Mac.local apsd[44748]: APSMessageStore - Enabling auto vacuum.
Jul 12 18:25:29 Mac.local apsd[44748]: APSMessageStore - Enabling WAL journal mode.
Jul 12 18:25:29 Mac.local apsd[44748]: APSMessageStore - Enabling Foreign Key support.
```

Comment: currently there is a CloudKit bug with update notifications. Did you try your app with adding a new record? For more info about the update bug see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7288

Comment: @EdwinVermeer that's interesting. However, I don't get notifications on record creation either.

Comment: In the target application capabilities, to you have Background Modes on for Remote notifications?

Comment: Is your app in the background when sending the notification?

Comment: The app has always been in foreground but I have added background capabilities with no success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your notification registration is correct for iOS 8, but on OS X you have to use `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` method of `NSApplication` and on iOS 7 the `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` method of `UIApplication`. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW2):

> An app must register with Apple Push Notification service (APNs) to
>   receive remote notifications sent by the app’s push provider. In iOS 8
>   and later, registration has four stages:
>
> 1. Register the notification types your app supports using
>      registerUserNotificationSettings:.
> 2. Register to receive push
>      notifications via APNs by calling your app’s
>      registerForRemoteNotifications method.
> 3. Store the device token returned
>      to the app delegate by the server for a successful registration, or
>      handle registration failure gracefully.
> 4. Forward the device token to
>      the app’s push provider.
>
> **(In iOS 7, instead of the first two steps,
>   you register by calling the registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: method
>   of UIApplication, and in OS X by calling the
>   registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: method of NSApplication.)**

Also implement [`didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ro#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) instead of `didReceiveRemoteNotification`:

> Use this method to process incoming remote notifications for your app.
>   Unlike the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method, which is
>   called only when your app is running in the foreground, the system
>   calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or
>   background. In addition, if you enabled the remote notifications
>   background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the
>   suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a remote
>   notification arrives. However, the system does not automatically
>   launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the
>   user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system
>   attempts to launch your app automatically again.

If you want the notifications to wake your app, make sure to edit `Info.plist` and check the "Enable Background Modes" and "Remote notifications" check boxes:

[image]

Since you want a silent notification, per documentation, you should only send the "content-available" flag to 1, so that's correct. But there are other users that had problems with silent notifications and apparently, sending the "sound" property as an empty string did help ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239737/silent-push-notification-in-ios-7-does-not-work)), so you could try to set `CKNotificationInfo.soundName` to an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, Baris. I did correctly register on OS X; the code just was not listed in my question. I always tested on iOS 8, so the registration there should be correct. The apps have been in foreground when I tested but I also added the background notifications and `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` but it still is not called. To me it is very mysterious...

Comment: @codingFriend1 See my updated answer: Try setting `CKNotificationInfo.soundName` to an empty string. Maybe it helps, it seems to have worked for [others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239737/silent-push-notification-in-ios-7-does-not-work)...

Comment: Yes! That was the missing puzzle piece. `soundName` has to be set in order to receive notifications.
I'm sorry that it took me so long to verify this and you only received half of the bounty. Anyway: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 12):

The [2015 WWDC CloudKit Tips & Tricks video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=715) pointed out that if you want to send a silent push notification, you need to set the `shouldSendContentAvailable` to true on your notificationInfo dictionary, like so:

```
let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
notificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!! I was struggling for the method not being called when the app is in background for more than 4 hours now.