# Handler Remote Notification background

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have this problem now, I need to handle the info of push notification when app in backround, I mean, even not tap the notifcation.
That mean this **application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler** must be called in background !
Here is my code for it

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{

    NSLog(@"full message %@", userInfo);
    NSDictionary *aps = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    NSLog(@"full aps %@", aps);
    NSString *custom = [userInfo objectForKey:@"custom"];
    NSLog(@"full custom %@",custom);
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificationRemote" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

I really need handle the info, such that save it to local everytime I have any notification, no matter I tap in push notification.

I search and I saw that I need content-available for my payload, but I can't find it in Firebase Console Notification.

Comment: hi , i have a similar scenario but slightly modification required , like when i get the push notification ,the app should get active in background and do the task given in , ( like user's location update code ) ,- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo , but my app would not get active until user taps on the notification . so , how would i get this done while app is in background ? dose anyone know the solution for this ?

Comment: @Moxarth Have you found solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you need content-available key in payload for silent push notification.

for more about FCM, U can see this link:
[Firebase silent apns notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570200/firebase-silent-apns-notification)

Comment: I know it but anyway to put content-available in firebase console?

Comment: from firebase console it seems not feasible for now. you have to use their push notification API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FireBase Cloud Function to create a payload and Fire a Notification.You can handle events in the Firebase Realtime Database.
The Realtime Database supports the onWrite() event, which triggers anytime data is created, destroyed, or changed in a specified database location.
Please refer this tutorial for detail which may help you 
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/serverless-apps-with-firebase-cloud-functions--cms-28557

Comment: but i cant do with firebase console ?

Comment: you need to write the cloud function locally in Node.js and deploy that with firebase.please see the sample code on https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js