# Firebase messaging handle custom data in background on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I send this to Firebase:

```
{
    "to" : "/topics/12344",
    "priority" : "high",
    "data" : {
      "c" : "sometext",
      "t" : "someothertext"
    },
  }
```

On Android I can create custom notification using the "data" payload with accessing its objects. I don't have to send the message title and body because I create custom text. This works even if the app is closed.

On iOS I can access the custom data using:

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
}
```

But it only prints if the the app is opened, not when closed. If I send the "notification array" to Firebase, it creates a notification when the app is closed, but I am not able to access the custom payload.

My question: How can I access the custom payload on iOS when the app is closed and create a notification?

Comment: hey, no solution ?. I have the same problem.

Comment: is there a way to receive the push notification in background only using the data payload?

Answer (score 0):

If app is closed or die , only Notification can be passed to the app
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

**When in the background**, apps receive the notification payload in the notification tray, and only handle the data payload when the user taps on the notification.

**When in the foreground**, your app receives a message object with both payloads available.

```
 {
    "to" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
```

Comment: is there a way to receive the push notification in background only using the data payload?

Comment: @Andrea do you mean silent notification?

Comment: yes, I want to handle myself the notification, I only need the data payload, since in Android when only data is added, it can be handled in background and in foreground, i would like the same behaviour in iOS, is it possible?

Comment: Shortly, yes, it is possible. You can read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37621274/3527461 and after that, read FireBase documentation ( link in answer )