# How to get notification data when user not tap on notification alert just click on app in ios using obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, background, notifications

I am working on app that receiving notification from server its working fine.
When my app is on **background mode** and **server send notification** iPhone shows **notification alert**.

### Problem

if i **click to** that notification alert **my app comes to foreground mode** 
**method** `didReceiveRemoteNotification` **called** 
then i easily get notification data and perform some action according to notification data.
But if **i click to app,** **not notification alert** then **app comes in foreground mode but**
**method**`didReceiveRemoteNotification` **not called**.

### What i want?

Is there **any method that check** **when app in background mode**,is there **any notification receive** or not,if receive then **get his data**,when **app comes in foreground mode?**

Comment: I am facing same problem.

Comment: Samiul Islam Sami ,did you slove this?

Comment: Did you check with Content-Available key in payload?

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)

Comment: Karthikeyan,how can i check,i already told in question that method not called.

Comment: Read this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html

Comment: sorry i forgot to told that i am configuring push notification from fire base not from apns

Comment: I am not sure about fire base, but u can do that with fire base also

Comment: Karthikeyan,i can't do that yet if you know that then please tell me lillte bit more...Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570200/firebase-silent-apns-notification

Comment: Read their doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: No. This method not called when app is kill. @vky

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to accomplish what you want unless you click the notification and read it's data in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

you can use pull mechanism to store notifications in server and read them when app opens from API request **facebook** does this