# Firebase silent notification lose (iOS)

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I used FCM for topic messaging with silent notification.

I have android and iOS app.

This is the sample JSON that I used in PHP

```
{ 
  "to" : "/topics/mytopic",
  "priority": "high",
  "content_available": true,
  "data" : {
     "<key>" : "<string>",
     "<key2>" : "<string>"
 }
```

I subscripted the same topic with android and iOS, then send to both.

iOS part always lost some messages

EX:

Send 10 messages

android: 10

iOS: 8

I searched the web and only found if battery level is less than 20% it will lost message.

(I test this behavior it's really happened, but not related to my cases. My battery level is always high in my test cases)

I have some questions, can someone help me?

1. Is any other possible situation to cause lose message?
2. Is any code I lost and need to check? (EX: iOS part)
3. Or lost some message is normal, FCM doesn't guarantee to send 100%

Comment: This page suggests that Apple will require a lower priority for background / silent notifications: https://onesignal.com/blog/ios-13-introduces-4-breaking-changes-to-notifications/  So you might try a lower priority and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I change priority, it seems not effect. 
But thanks for your provided URL, I add apns-push-type in my header part.
I can get all messages on my test in iOS now!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does not guarantee delivery of silent notifications in iOS by using content-available.

As per firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) for content-available,

"Note that silent notifications in APNs are not guaranteed to be delivered, and can depend on factors such as the user turning on Low Power Mode, force quitting the app, etc. On Android, data messages wake the app by default."

Here's a workaround that I think might work for you.

For your iOS device, send a notification payload with mutable_content as true, a dummy notification object and some sort of flag in your data object that indicates this is meant to be a silent notification(something like isSilentNotif=true).

Now write a notificationservice that extends UNNotificationServiceExtension. You will get control in your notification service before the notification is displayed to the user. Here check for the flag you included (isSilentNotif) and hide the notification programmatically if the flag is true and perform the background operation you wanted to perform here.

Comment: Because of content-available, silent notifications in APNs are not guaranteed to be delivered in iOS for some case.

So add mutable_content, it will not be a silent notification and will raise the sending rate in IOS.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "will raise the sending rate in IOS".

Comment: Oh, it means it will not lose some messages after workaround.

Comment: Raise sending received rate

Comment: Yes, I believe sending push messages with the notification object included with "priority": "high" will increase sending received rate.