# Reliable background synchronisation on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, synchronization

### Preamble

I wrote a mobile application which should show upcoming events. The app downloads it's data from server. Data is prepared in batches once every 24 hours and it's ready to be fetched after 4 am. This gives me a perfect opportunity to sync it overnight and to make new data immediately available when the user opens the app.

### Background fetch

This was my first approach for syncing data with the server. It's advertised as very powerful feature, but using it alone (out of the test environment) is not enough:

- There is no way to force background fetches to execute at exact intervals.

I thought that the frequency of background fetch operations could be configured

```
// Setup background fetch
let timeIntervalEveryHour: NSTimeInterval = 3600
let sharedApp = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
sharedApp.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(timeIntervalEveryHour)
```

but it's still dynamic and *I think it is never* for users who did't use app very often.

- If 'Background App Refresh' is disabled, which automatically happen if device is in 'Low power mode', background fetch won't be triggered.
- Other problems like [Data Protection](https://www.bipsync.com/blog/what-apple-doesnt-tell-you-about-background-fetch/) when device is locked and 30 seconds window for completion of all tasks are considered.

### Remote (silent) notifications

So I took the next step and configured the server to post silent notifications once the batch is ready just to found that this is also not enough:

- If application is force killed by the user or device is rebooted, notification won't be handled.
- Rate limits. Delivery will be delayed, this depends on a variety of factors that are not explicitly specified by Apple, but probably - battery life, whether phone is on cellular, etc.

  > Sometimes silent push notifications are dispatched when application starts, which could lead to race conditions with the check for manual synchronisation. So I'll try to force it by adding `"alert" = "";` to payload. (As it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427960/4524113))
- Silent Push notifications could be disabled by the user be setting off 'Background App Refresh' - [source](https://www.urbanairship.com/blog/watch-list-ios-8-opt-in-changes)

### Manual synchronisation

To be sure that data is always up to date, if it's not recently updated, when app comes to foreground user is presented with alert which asks for manual synchronisation. Also it could be started later from settings tab. Unfortunately, according to analytics, most of the fetch requests are made manually.

First run case is also handled.

### Next steps

I'm considering using VOIP notification. They should wake the app even if it's force killed. However I'm concerned that that would cause app get rejected.

### Questions

Is there something I'm missing? I know that background synchronisation depends on a variety of factors, there could be no internet connection and etc, but is there any way to make it more reliable?

Comment: Can someone answer this?

Comment: I still believe that I'm missing something, but deep inside I feel that I'm already using everything iOS could give. Probably this is the right way to preserve battery life, I don't know.

Comment: 2019, looks like we still have to alternative to scheduled tasks.